# Wordpress Sub Menu / Show Sister Pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently using this snippet to show children of the current page.

```
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.''); ?>
```

when I click one of those children pages the sub nav disappears because there are no child pages of the current page, so what I need it to do is continue to show the sister pages of the current page.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could request the parent ID instead of the post ID if there is no childs on the current page :

```
$page_query = new WP_Query();
$all_pages = $page_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));
$childs = get_page_children($post-ID, $all_pages);
if(!empty($childs)) {
    // display the page childs
    wp_list_pages($post->ID);
} else {
    // display the page siblings
    wp_list_pages(wp_get_post_parent_id($post->ID));
}
```

[`get_page_children`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children) is used to check if there is any child for the current page - the `WP_Query` part is needed for `get_page_children` which required an array of all the pages to look in.